# Order mismatch and similarity

Tags: r, dplyr, stringdist

I have two values which their order is mismatched and values are ideally same.
When i calculate the string similaratity the score between them is far away from its ideal score

```
col_1 = c("USA,UK,APAC")
col_2 = c("UK,APAC,USA")
library(stringdist)
stringdist(col_1,col_2,  method = 'jw')
```

How to identify that both col_1 and col_2 are similar even their order is miss-arranged.i.e is there any method to identify that both the values are ideally same

Answer (score 1):

If your values are consistently separated by commas, you could split on the comma, sort and then compare them.

```
spl_1 <- sort(unlist(strsplit(col_1, ',')))
spl_2 <- sort(unlist(strsplit(col_2, ',')))

stringdist(spl_1, spl_2, method = "jw")
```